# No SDK cache entry for extension! - Mac extension crash

Tags: macos, finder

I am writing my own finder extension. The extension works in most of the times, but sometimes on some of our machines it decides not to work anymore.

I so far did not manage to spot any pattern why this happens. The only point I got is it writes in the crashreport:

> No SDK cache entry for extension!

After googling I found that this problem happens sometimes in mac, and the solution is :

```
sudo /usr/libexec/xpchelper --rebuild-cache
```

But I would like to understand why this happens, so maybe someone here have some more insight what this mean, and what I can be doing wrong that causes this crash to happen.

The only thing I suspect is that our app removes and installs this extension quite often, but so far I could not verify if this is the cause

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your OS X installation. The simplest way, but not the fastest way, to fix it is to reinstall the OS. Unless you're in a hurry or have limited network access, that's what I suggest, especially since I don't know whether there are other problems with the installation. Please back up all data before reinstalling. You won't need the backup unless something goes wrong.
The advanced shortcut below, if it works, may save you some downtime (and the cost of a 5 GB download, if applicable.)

1. Back up all data.
2. Disconnect all external storage devices.
3. Start up in Recovery mode. Select a language, if prompted. The OS X Utilities screen will appear. One of the options is to install OS X. That's not what you're going to do.
4. This step is only necessary if you use FileVault 2. If you don't know what FileVault is, you're not using it. Go to the next step. Otherwise, launch Disk Utility, then select the icon of the FileVault volume ("Macintosh HD," unless you gave it a different name.) It will be nested below another drive icon. Click the Unlock button in the toolbar and enter your login password when prompted. Then quit Disk Utility to be returned to the main screen.
5. Select Get Help Online. Safari will launch. While in Recovery, you'll have no access to your bookmarks, but you won't need them. Load this web page.
6. Triple-click anywhere in the line below to select it:
   chflags norestricted /V*/*/S*/*/Caches
   Copy the selected text to the Clipboard by pressing the key combination command-C.
7. Quit Safari. From the menu bar, select
         Utilities ▹ Terminal
   The Terminal application will launch. Paste into the Terminal window by pressing the key combination command-V.
   Wait for a new line ending in a hash sign (#) to appear. Quit Terminal to be returned to the main screen.
8. Select
          ▹ Restart
   from the menu bar.
9. This step must be carried out after the restart and while you're logged in as an administrator—not in Recovery mode. If you have only one user account, you are the administrator.
   Select and copy this line as in Step 6:
   sudo /usr/libexec/xpchelper --rebuild-cache
   Paste into a Terminal window as before. You'll be prompted for your login password. Nothing will be displayed when you type it. Type carefully and then press return. If you don’t have a login password, you’ll need to set one before you can run the command. You may get a one-time warning to be careful. Confirm. You don't need to post the warning.
   If you see a message that your username "is not in the sudoers file," then you're not logged in as an administrator. Log in as one and start over.
   Wait for a new line ending in a dollar sign ($) to appear below what you entered.
10. Do as in Step 9 with this line:
    sudo /usr/libexec/*/app_sandbox_cache_builder --rebuild-cache
    You can then quit Terminal.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7388214?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: yes this is the answer where I found the solution of running "sudo /usr/libexec/xpchelper --rebuild-cache" my question is aimed to undesrtanding why I need to run this command and what does the error really mean